# Rotate two banners 50/50

Tags: php

I have two banners which I display on the page but they didn't appear equal times on page refresh. I want they to rotate on every page refresh. Right now banner1 can show 10 times from 10 refresh and banner2 not even one time.

```
<?php
  $banner1 = '<a href="BANNER1_URL" target="_blank"><img src="BANNER1_IMG_SRC" alt="BANNER1_ALT" title="BANNER1_TITLE"></a>';
  $banner2 = '<a href="BANNER2_URL" target="_blank"><img src="BANNER2_IMG_SRC" alt="BANNER2_ALT" title="BANNER2_TITLE"></a>';
  $banners = array($banner1, $banner2);
  shuffle($banners);
?>
<div id="ban">
  <?php print $banners[0] ?>
</div>
```

I've tried to put for example `rand(1,2)` but the page crash. This is what I've tried

```
    <?php
  $banner1 = '<a href="BANNER1_URL" target="_blank"><img src="BANNER1_IMG_SRC" alt="BANNER1_ALT" title="BANNER1_TITLE"></a>';
  $banner2 = '<a href="BANNER2_URL" target="_blank"><img src="BANNER2_IMG_SRC" alt="BANNER2_ALT" title="BANNER2_TITLE"></a>';
  $banners = array($banner1, $banner2);
  $num = rand (1,2);
  shuffle($banners);
?>
<div id="ban">
  <?php print $num($banners[0]) ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the error that your last example is throwing?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in...`

Comment: The thing about picking something at random is that the same banner will be shown 10 times in a row one of 1024 times, while it will average out to 50/50 over time. You'll have to keep some sort of history to be able to do more advanced logic for which banner to show next.

Comment: It is because you are trying to use $num (variable) as a function. See my answer for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the number that you randomly get you need to get that index from the list of banners;

```
<?php
  $banner1 = '<a href="BANNER1_URL" target="_blank"><img src="BANNER1_IMG_SRC" alt="BANNER1_ALT" title="BANNER1_TITLE"></a>';
  $banner2 = '<a href="BANNER2_URL" target="_blank"><img src="BANNER2_IMG_SRC" alt="BANNER2_ALT" title="BANNER2_TITLE"></a>';
  $banners = array($banner1, $banner2);
  $num = rand (0,1);
?>
<div id="ban">
  <?php print $banners[$num] ?>
</div>
```

Also change your "random-generator" to get 0 or 1 as the index and remove the shuffle (as mentioned by MatsLindh in the comments)

**EDIT:** As requested in the comments, here is an example of how to store which banner was shown in the SESSION and then show the other.

```
<?php
  $banner1 = ...
  $banner2 = ...
  $banners = array($banner1, $banner2);
  $bannerIndex = 0;
  if(isset($_SESSION['bannerIndex'])){
     $bannerIndex = (intval($_SESSION['bannerIndex']) + 1) % 2;
  }
  $_SESSION['bannerIndex'] = $bannerIndex;
?>
<div id="ban">
  <?php print $banners[$bannerIndex]; ?>
</div>
```

This is just to give you an idea and has not been tested.

Comment: There is either no need for `rand()` or no need for `shuffle` - you don't need both. In this case just doing `rand()` will suffice (and be more effective).

Comment: True! Just copied post and it is too early on the morning for these things :)

Comment: Same result as before. they are not 50/50

Comment: You could also just do `print $banners[array_rand($banners)]` and be done with `rand()` alltogether

Comment: @Goro They will not be exactly 50/50 since it is using Random, if you need EXACTLY 50/50 then you can store which is being shown right now in a SESSION variable and check which was last shown.

Comment: Can you provide me with some example?